# Category id not receiving

Tags: php, pdo

i'm currently bussy with getting a forum system in PDO. i have done the index and i'm now bussy with the category but on a strange way i do not receive the category. When i'm on category.php?id=1 it says that the category does not exist. The following code is the part for receiving the category id

```
  <?php
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT
                cat_id,
                cat_name,
                cat_description
            FROM
                categories
            WHERE
                cat_id = " . $_GET['id']);

$result = $sql->rowCount();

if(!$result)
{
    echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.';
}
else
{
    if($sql || ($result== 0))
    {
        echo 'This category does not exist.';
    }?>
```

It's showing the this category ford not exist line. i have no idea what is wrong the table is correct. this is the table. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d1c4 .

i'm a beginner with PDO so maybe it's just a error that is simple as i have no idea.

for the people that want to know what the answer was. Here the script i'm using now :

```
    <?php
//first select the category based on $_GET['cat_id']
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description
    FROM categories WHERE cat_id = :catid');
$sql->bindParam(':catid', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->rowCount();


if($result === FALSE){
    echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.';
}
elseif(count($result) === 0){
    echo 'This category does not exist.';
}
else{
```

Comment: Why are you checking `$sql || ($result== 0)`?  This will print `'This category does not exist.'` if the query worked!

Comment: @RocketHazmat Because if the result == 0 (there is no category with that id) then it does not exist

Comment: But look what happens if it *does* exist!  If the category exits, `$result` will *not* equal `0` and `$sql` will *not* be `FALSE`.  Therefore you'll get `if($sql || ($result== 0))`.  Which will be `if(TRUE || FALSE)`.  Which is `TRUE`, so `This category does not exist.'` is printed.  Even though it *does* exist.  You need to check your logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off, since you are using PDO, you *should* be using prepared queries.  It's real easy.

```
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description
    FROM categories WHERE cat_id = :catid');
$sql->execute(array(':catid' => $_GET['id']));
```

This will take care of any escaping for you and keep you safe from SQL injection.  Next, you need to fetch the data from the SQL query you just ran:

```
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Finally, you can check if the category exists or not.

```
if($result === FALSE){
    echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.';
}
elseif(count($result) === 0){
    echo 'This category does not exist.';
}
else{
    echo 'Category found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the point in using a row count?
If you need a category - **why not to fetch it already**?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories  WHERE cat_id = ?";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$row = $stm->fetch();
if (!$row) {
    // no category found
}
```

Note that you have to use **prepared statements** as shown above.
You have to also set proper error reporting as explained in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: I'm still getting the category does not exist.